# al instalar el apk de mi app ionic en mi smartphone no funciona completa

Tags: android-studio, ionic, ionic4, apk

necesito ayuda con mi app de ionic, ya que al ejecutar "ionic cordova build android" e instalar el apk generado en mi smartphone solo funciona a medias, algunos elementos no aparecen, a pesar de que al hacer lo mismo en android studio con un virtual device funciona completamente sin problema alguno. Me gustaria saber si el problema es mi smartphone, es un samsung A10, por favor ayuda.
Aqui les muestro partes del codigo para que entiendan como funciona la app, es basica asi que es corto el codigo, este es el objeto que contiene los elementos que se mostraran en la app:

```
instrumentos = [
    { 
      nombre:"flauta",
      imagen:"../../assets/imagenes/flauta.png",
      audio:"../../assets/sonidos/flauta.mp3"
    },
    { 
      nombre:"platillos",
      imagen:"../../assets/imagenes/platillos.png",
      audio:"../../assets/sonidos/platillos.mp3"
    },
    { 
      nombre:"bombo1",
      imagen:"../../assets/imagenes/bombo1.png",
      audio:"../../assets/sonidos/bombo1.mp3"
    },
    { 
      nombre:"bombo2",
      imagen:"../../assets/imagenes/bombo2.png",
      audio:"../../assets/sonidos/bombo2.mp3"
    }
  ]
```

Este es codigo del html:

```
ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Mi App Musical
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-label>Toca el instrumento para hacer música</ion-label>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let instrumento of instrumentos">
        <ion-card (click)="reproducirSonido(instrumento)">
          <ion-img [src]="instrumento.imagen"></ion-img>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Este es el codigo de la funcion reproducirSonido():

```
reproducirSonido(instrumento){
    let sonido = new Audio();
    sonido.src = instrumento.audio;
    sonido.load();
    sonido.play();
  }
```

respondere mi pregunta mas abajo para agregar lo que falte y no hacer esto tan largo aqui.

Comment: La pregunta en su estado actual, es muy amplia. No vemos qué es lo que no aparece, no vemos qué debería aparecer y el código detrás de ello. ¿Puedes añadir detalles?

Comment: Recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: disculpen, es que soy nuevo en la comunidad de stackoverflow, dejame recopilar unas imagenes y les mostrare lo que sucede